# pop up buffer / window when using python-shell-send-buffer

Tags: python

I like using python-shell-send-buffer, but I am annoyed of looking for the command's buffer.

So I'm looking for a function, that recognizes whether the buffer is already displayed. Since I use two windows on one frame, when coding in python, it would be nice if the function also checks if there are already two windows on the current frame. If not, it has to split the frame horizontally. Additionally I want the buffers to be automatically positioned, as I'm used to have my source code on the left side and the python shell with the output on the right side.

Comment: Nothing. I'm new to emacs and coding in general. This task is beyond my elisp skills :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a very simple solution(thx to helm). There's a function in elpy called elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer. It provides everything I wanted except the buffer positioning.
I also like the possibility to run marked code. If nothing is marked, the whole buffer is sent to the python shell. Very nice :)